# Fabric.js text width being ignored

Tags: html, fabricjs

I am trying to add text to a canvas from a form input.
Is there a way to automatically wrap the fabricjs text, to fit inside the canvas?

<strike>There are 3 issues I am trying to overcome:
1. the text doesn't respect the 'text.left' position if the string is longer than the given space.
2. I cannot escape newlines, so the \n is written inline with the text.
3. Center-align is completely ignored until text is updated.</strike>

Here is my fabric text:

```
var text = new fabric.Text($('#myInput').text(), {
    left: 10,
    top: 12,
    width: 230,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 28,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Nue, Helvetica, Sans-Serif, Arial, Trebuchet MS'
});
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dval/Kz7VL/) showing the issue.

<strike>How do I insert a newline?
How do I center-align the text in the given text-block?
How do position the text-block on the canvas without having to make edits?</strike>

Edit:

I have found that part of my problem was from using a text input. I changed that to a textarea element, and now newlines can be inserted easily. Weirdly, centering also works when I do this.

I guess the only issue is that the text doesn't auto-wrap when it's wider than the given text-block width. So, instead of wrapping and adding lines, it just extends beyond the canvas.

is there a way to do wordwrap type styling or do I have to count characters and insert linebreaks?

Comment: Did you try scaleToWidth  (http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line12065) method?

Comment: Brilliant! Can you submit that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this one's old, but I ran into this same issue.  In my case, the text is in a group, so I want it to wrap to a specific width, but allow the group to resize (so I couldn't use the `TextBox`).  I ended up pre-processing the string to put line breaks when the set width is met.

```
 function addTextBreaks(text, width, fontSize) {
    text = text.trim();
    var words = text.toString().split(' '),
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        idx = 1,
        newString = '';
    context.font = fontSize + 'px Lato';
    while (words.length > 0 && idx <= words.length) {
        var str = words.slice(0, idx).join(' '),
            w = context.measureText(str).width;
        if (w > width) {
            if (idx == 1) {
                idx = 2;
            }
            newString += words.slice(0, idx - 1).join(' ');
            newString += '\n';
            words = words.splice(idx - 1);
            idx = 1;
        }
        else { idx += 1;}
    }
    if (idx > 0) {
        var txt = words.join(' ');
        newString += txt;
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: I [updated the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dval/Kz7VL/) with your function, with one modification. I wrapped the logic in for-loop, `var lines = text.toString().split('\n')`  to account for user inserted line breaks. It then breaks each line as its own element. This is great! thank you.